# Dynamic scaffolding of multiple domain classes with single controller

Tags: grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

For my web application in grails I have 3 admin controlling domain classes and no need of special UIs. For this I have decided to use dynamic scaffolding.

static scaffold = true; is scaffolding only one domain class.

Is there any way to scaffold all these 3 domain classes with a single controller. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution.

We can scaffold a domain class from another controller by mentioning the name of domain class needed to scaffold dynamically.

For example:

```
static scaffold = User;
```

This scaffolding is happening in run-time only. So if we need to avoid scaffolding and if we wish to add actions manually we can eliminate the above code of line.